# mongoose /node how to handle exception

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an validation during save of a model. the validation is going against the empty value and trying to split it and it errors out..it thrown out the node itself. I am passing a call back to save it not being called...but if there i a proper error(when I trim and do the check and send false it calls the callback..) how should this be normally handled.

```
C:\WN\models\user.coffee:18
                        # validator: wed.checkCity
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
    at model.mongoose.Schema.aboutme.validate (C:\WN\models\user.coffee:18:23)
    at C:\WN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:627:28
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (C:\WN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:614:19)
    at C:\WN\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:956:9
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: Paste the code which actually throw the Error ?

Comment: Doesn't matter..I am not looking to solve the error. As I mentioned..I am trying to see if there is an exception..it should not bring nodejs server down. I wanted the callback to the save method called...the callback is working fine since I tested with false on the validation and it comes back as I mentioned

Comment: You'd normally include checks in the validator that would prevent the code that would otherwise throw the exception from being called.

Comment: Of course there is an exception, a `TypeError`... Without seeing code there's not much else anyone can tell you.

Comment: you would still need exception handing . and I don't want my node going down Iam passing callback to the save of mongoose model. I don't want know how to stop the error. I want to understand if mongoose is not throwing error back to my callback .. there is process.on unhandled exception  as last resort

Comment: Your custom validator functions shouldn't ever throw exceptions, so I'd argue that you actually do want that crashing your app so that you notice and fix the problem rather than hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Here the codes what I used to catch the exception thrown by Node.js

```
// Error configuration
function bootErrorHandler(app) {

  // When no more middleware require execution, aka
  // our router is finished and did not respond, we
  // can assume that it is "not found". Instead of
  // letting Connect deal with this, we define our
  // custom middleware here to simply pass a NotFound
  // exception

  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    next(new NotFound(req.url));
  })

  // Provide our app with the notion of NotFound exceptions

  function NotFound(path){
    this.name = 'NotFound'
    if (path) {
      Error.call(this, 'Cannot find ' + path)
      this.path = path
    } else {
      Error.call(this, 'Not Found')
    }
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, arguments.callee)
  }

  /**
   * Inherit from `Error.prototype`.
   */

  NotFound.prototype.__proto__ = Error.prototype;

  // We can call app.error() several times as shown below.
  // Here we check for an instanceof NotFound and show the
  // 404 page, or we pass on to the next error handler.

  // These handlers could potentially be defined within
  // configure() blocks to provide introspection when
  // in the development environment.

  //var logFile = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/log/error', {'flags': 'a'});

  var mongooseError = function(err, res){
      var messages = {
        'required': "%s is required",
        'min': "%s below minimum",
        'max': "%s above maximum",
        'enum': "%s not an allowed value"
      };
      var errors = [];
      _.each(Object.keys(err.errors), function(field){
        var errObj = err.errors[field];
        if (!messages.hasOwnProperty(errObj.type))
            errors.push(errObj.type);
        else{
            errors.push(require('util').format(messages[errObj.type], errObj.path));
        }
      });
        res.render('info/500', {
            status: 500,
            error: errors,
            showStack: '',
            title: 'Oops! Something went wrong',
            layout: 'layouts/500'
        });
  }

  app.error(function(err, req, res, next){
          //logFile.write('\r\n===' + new Date() + '===\r\n');
          //logFile.write(err.stack);

          if (err instanceof NotFound) {
                  logger.error(err.stack);
                  res.render('info/404', {
                          status: 404,
                          error: err,
                          showStack: app.settings.showStackError,
                          title: 'Oops! The page you requested desn\'t exist'
                  })
          }
          else {
                  logger.error(err.stack);
                  if (err.name === 'ValidationError')
                     mongooseError(err, res);
                  else
                    res.render('info/500', {
                        status: 500,
                        error: err,
                        showStack: app.settings.showStackError,
                        title: 'Oops! Something went wrong!',
                        layout: 'layouts/500'
                    });
         }
  })

}
```

Also you can add the following codes at the beginning of your node app file.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  if ('stack' in err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  }
});
```